# How does $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ look like

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

An extremely boring day at work, so I've started writing some math nonsense on a sheet of a paper, and came to $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ (as a quotient topological space). I wrote then $=\Bbb S_1$, but then I thought that I never studied topology properly, so likely there's a mistake. My second thought was that this space is a bundle of circles all glued at a single point. Would that be correct? Overall, is there anything interesting to read about $\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z^n$ that will save me from boredom?

Comment: It's the circle all right. Think of the mapping $x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{C}$, or rather to the unit circle. It's a homomorphism with kernel $\Bbb{Z}$, so the first isomorphism theorem gives you what you want.

Comment: Re: the last sentence. Elliptic curves are fascinating. Topologically they are of the form $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a tilted copy of $\Bbb{Z}^2$, i.e. a lattice. Studying elliptic curves, their number theoretic properties in particular, should keep you busy for the rest of your days :-)

Comment: As a quotient of topological spaces it is a bundle of circles. As a quotient by a group action it is a single circle as @JyrkiLahtonen writes.

Comment: Ahh! You won't be equating all the cosets, just the points of $\Bbb{Z}$. Sorry about being an algebraist :-)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek: cool! would you mind making an answer out of your comment?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: indeed, that was my confusion at first as well.

Comment: I don't know if it's enough to alleviate your boredom, but the  $\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z^n$ for larger n are quite different from $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$. For example, they are simply-connected while $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ has fundamental group the free group on countably many generators. To get a bunch of n-spheres joined at one point you need to take the quotient by something like the union of all the (n-1)-spheres in $\Bbb R^n$ centred on the origin and with integer radii.

Comment: as a quotient of topological spaces it has no countable local base at the point to which $\Bbb Z$ is smashed.

Comment: My previous comment contains at least one error. To increase the excitement I'll leave it unspecified.

Comment: @DavidHartley: thanks! let's see what today brings

Answer (score 1):

I'll summarize the comments for the sake of providing an answer.

As a quotient of topological spaces, it is indeed a bundle of circles as you describe. As a quotient of groups on the other hand (an "algebraic" quotient), it is $\mathbb{S}^1$.

There certainly are interesting things to read about $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$. As in the previous case, exactly what you think this is depends on the kind of quotient you're taking.

Perhaps something fun for you to do would be to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$ is (homeomorphic to) a product of $\mathbb{S}^1$s.

Comment: Although the usual technical term is bouquet of circles, not bundle (but I understand why you used the word)